# Scrolling with TexShop

Tags: texshop

I just udpated to TexShop 3.41 (and Maverick). When I scroll on the pdf file I get stuck at the end/begin of every page : I can only scroll within one page but not go from page to page. Any idea how to fix it ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is not really on topic here. You should ask the maintainers of this software. I don't know it at all, but most pdf-Viewers have a menu item "View" and there something like "show pages continuously". Have a look, if you can find something like that there (or in the preferences).

Comment: This is from some bug-fix report: "[...] bug in the Preview Preferences for 'Default page style.' The buttons for 'Double Sided' and 'Single Sided, Continuous' were [...]" I hope you will find this option somewhere...

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I don't think this is off-topic, as TeXShop is specifically a front-end to TeX and friends. It would be if the behavior is a bug that can't be solved without changing the source code. I'm downloading v. 3.41 just now and will investigate.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I tried what you suggest and played with the pdf display preferences but couldn't find my way out of the problem.
Also the bug report you mention seems to relate to some german version and to have been fixed. But this issue seems to have come around with previous versions of TexShop also.

Comment: @vicophys Yes, the bug report is old. I just wanted to give you some words used by TeXShop in order to facilitate the search. We will see if egreg finds something. I am not on Mac.

Comment: I see no difference in scrolling (TeXShop 3.41, Mac OS X Maverick) from the previous version of TeXShop. Here's a [picture of my preference pane](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lxTSM.png)

Comment: Ok you solved it this was the multiple page thing. I should have figured myself ... Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my TeXShop viewer preference pane:

[image: picture]

You probably have “Single-Page” as “Default Page Style”.